# Custom pagination generates title 404

Tags: pagination, query-posts, 404-error

I know it's a common problem, but I tried every solution appeared on this stackexchange.

Every solution has failed (maybe because I'm still a newbie).

I've this query on index.php page:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }
query_posts('cat=4,8,12&posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged);
if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>
[...]
```

I've enabled permalinks and I'm also using a (famous) SEO plugin.

My articles page URL is: `http://www.mysite.com/news/page/x` where x is the number of the pagination.

Everything is working fine for the first 24 "pages", but from the 25th page the title become "Page not Found" and in breadcrumbs I can see "404".

The weird thing is that articles are still shown correctly with the correct pagination.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using a custom query? Use `pre_get_posts` to properly modify the query variables before the main query executes

Answer (score 0):

Using query_posts is generally not recommended. Looking at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), it specifically states:

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

Note the "especially often when dealing with posts pagination" part.

I would try re-writing your code with one of the other suggested methods and see if that changes the behavior.